# Loopback mongodb connector no hostname or hostnames provided in connection string

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

When I start loopback server I'm getting this error. Everything in code looks perfect. I am passing hostname, database name, username, password and port.

```
 /var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:24
        throw new Error('no hostname or hostnames provided in connection string');
    ^

Error: no hostname or hostnames provided in connection string
    at module.exports (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:24:11)
    at connect (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:125:16)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:109:3)
    at MongoDB.connect (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:113:25)
    at Object.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:70:26)
    at DataSource.setup (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:332:17)
    at new DataSource (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:109:8)
    at Registry.createDataSource (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:349:12)
    at dataSourcesFromConfig (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:415:19)
    at EventEmitter.app.dataSource (/var/www/investickations_web/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:222:12)
```

Answer (score 3):

Found a bug in url_parser.js of Loopback-MongoDB-Connector. If you have @ in your password string, it fails to parse and build MongoDB Connection String.

**So either prepare your connection string yourself and pass it as 'url' field in datasources JSON or change your MongoDB password so it doesn't contain @ character.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample connection string to connect to mongo. As achintverma said don't use @ in password.

```
"mongoDS": {
    "url": "mongodb://paanoop:*password*@ds035683.mongolab.com:1234/fsbs",
    "database": "",
    "password": "*password*",
    "name": "your data source",
    "user": "username",
    "connector": "mongodb"
}
```